# Android Studio - 'constants.dart' file becomes a .txt file

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

This has only become a problem in the past week. I've had many Flutter projects in Android Studio over the past year, and nearly every project has a `constants.dart` file that behaves appropriately as a `.dart` file.

However, the exact filename `constants.dart` is instantly converted to a `.txt` file as of last week. If I name it anything else, such as `constantsA.dart` then it remains a `.dart` file and behaves as expected.

I've searched in vain online to find out why this is happening, but I can't find any info. I'm running the latest versions of Android Studio, Dart, and Flutter.

Answer (score 4):

Select the file in the project navigator, then go to menu *File > File properties > Associate with file type...*

[image]

Select "Dart" and the fille will be opened as dart file again.

[image]